How to prevent the creation of the field 'fid'
I'm creating some layers with PyQGIS, defining their fields and saving them in a GeoPackage file, but an unwanted field 'fid' is being created. How can I prevent this field from being created?
This is the code I'm using:
parent = self.iface.mainWindow()
fn, fnOK = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(caption="Nome da rede", directory=QgsProject.instance().homePath(), filter="GeoPackage (*.gpkg)")
if fnOK:
    QMessageBox.information(parent, "Operação concluída", f"Salvando {fn}")
    path = str(os.path.dirname(fn))

    # Criando os layers
    lyr_1 = QgsVectorLayer("linestring", 'tubulacoes', "memory")
    lyr_1.setCrs(QgsProject.instance().crs())
    lyr_2 = QgsVectorLayer("point", 'reservatorios', "memory")
    lyr_2.setCrs(QgsProject.instance().crs())

    # Criando os campos (Field) dos layers
    pr_1 = lyr_1.dataProvider()  # Acessando o provedor de dados do Layer lyr_1
    lyr_1.startEditing()  # Entrando no modo de edição
    pr_1.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("Node1", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("Node2", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("Comprimento", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Material", QVariant.String),
                        QgsField("Diâmetro", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("Diâmetro Interno", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Espessura", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Rugosidade", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("M. Elasticidade", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("C. Poisson", QVariant.Double)])
    lyr_1.commitChanges()  # Confimar alterações

    # Reservatório
    pr_2 = lyr_2.dataProvider()  # Acessando o provedor de dados do Layer lyr_2
    lyr_2.startEditing()  # Entrando no modo de edição
    pr_2.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField("X-Coord", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Y-Coord", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Nome", QVariant.String),
                        QgsField("Elevação", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Altura Fuste", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Diâmetro", QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField("Altura Útil", QVariant.Double),])
    lyr_2.commitChanges()  # Confimar alterações

    # Salvando os layers no disco
    # criando o geopackage e colocando todas as camadas dentro
    lst = [lyr_1, lyr_2]
    params = {'LAYERS': lst,
              'OUTPUT': fn,
              'OVERWRITE': False,  # Important!
              'SAVE_STYLES': True,
              'SAVE_METADATA': True,
              'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY': False}
    processing.run("native:package", params)

    # Alterar a fonte de dados dos layers
    lyr_1.setDataSource(fn, lyr_1.name(), 'ogr')
    lyr_2.setDataSource(fn, lyr_2.name(), 'ogr')

    # Abrindo os layers no QGIS
    # self.iface.addVectorLayer(fn, nome_rede, "ogr")
    sub_lyr_names = [l.GetName() for l in ogr.Open(fn)]
    for lyr_name in sorted(sub_lyr_names, reverse=True):
        vl = QgsVectorLayer(f'{fn}|layername={lyr_name}', lyr_name, 'ogr')
        if vl.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(parent, "Aviso", "Nenhum arquivo salvo")



GeoPackage tables must have an feature ID column that must be of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL. By the screen capture I can't say if the "ID" that you have created is such PK, or if the automatically created "fid" has that role.

You can hide this field in the QGIS interface if it is an eyesore. You can find Organize Tables columns button and hide it with a switcher. The field will still exist in the attribute table.
